# The number of orders pairs of integers satisfying the equation. [Further doubt on a closed question]

Tags: polynomials

I have a wrong approach to the following closed  question:

[The number of ordered pairs satisfying the equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547626/the-number-of-ordered-pairs-satisfying-the-equation)

The equation specified is:

$x^2+6x+y^2 = 4$

It can be observed that this is the equation of a circle; thereby eight pairs are found.

What if the equation is solved in the following manner:

Let the equation be rewritten as-

$H(x) = x^2+6x+y^2 - 4$

$H(x) = f(x) + g(x)$

Now the original equation will be satisfied if f(x) = 0 and g(x) = 0

Right?

If yes then:

Case 1: 
$f(x) = x^2+6x - 4$

$g(x) = y^2$

And case 2:
$f(x) = x^2+6x$

$g(x) = y^2 - 4$

Under the above assumption we get 6 pairs; which obviously is the wrong answer.

Will anyone be kind enough to point me why my analysis is?

*My apologies for the dumb question at the end of  a long post and thanks in advance for your patience*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis by cases is only valid if the cases are exhaustive. (That is, they cover all possibilities.) Your list of two cases is not exhaustive. In particular, $H(x,y) = x^2+6x+y^2 - 4$ can be written as $f(x)+g(y)$ with $f(x) = x^2+6x + k$ and $g(y)=y^2-4-k$ for any real number $k$. Only some values of $k$ yield integer solutions to $H(x,y)=0$, and for example, this one (which you didn’t consider) does: $f(x) = (x^2+6x + 5)$ and $g(y)=(y^2 - 9)=0$. Also worth noting, your Case 1 yields no integer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for integers $x, y.$ We have $(x+3)^2 +y^2=13.$ The only solutions in integers $x+3, y$ are $\{|x+3|,|y|\}=\{2,3\}$ because the only way to get $13$ as the sum of two integer squares is $13=4+9.$